# MVC3 WebGrid Pager Position Custmization

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Iam devloping web application with mvc3.In one my view iam using WebGrid.In webgrid pager control by default it showing on webgrid footer only.So how to change pager position from footer to top of webgrid or else how to show pager both webgrid top and bottom.Please give idea about this.

In Onready function change the footer position but once click on next button its reset to original position.....Please give some sample for this

Thanks & regards
Narasimha

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`WebGrid.Pager()` function returns the HTML code for the pager of your webgrid.

In this way you can have two pagers from top and bottom of the table,

```
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model, defaultSort:"Name");
}
@grid.Pager()
@grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column("Name", format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink((string)item.Name, "Details", "Product", new {id=item.ProductId}, null)</text>),
    grid.Column("ListPrice", header: "List Price", format: @<text>@item.ListPrice.ToString("0.00")</text>)
    )
)
```

Both pagers work together.

If you want to hide the bottom pager, you can select and hide the `<tfoot>` tag using Jquery or Javascript.

Comment: If you want to study more on WebGrid, you can use this(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx) article